# Is the content of an HTML Canvas tag automatically created as a PNG file?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When I right click an image that was drawn into a `<canvas>` tag , the only file option type to save as, is `.png`. Even if the file uploaded is a .jpeg, the only option shown in the short cut menu to `Save Image As` is a .png file. Is image data drawn into a `<canvas>` tag as a png file?

### HTML

```
<form class='frmUpload'>
  <input name="picOneUpload" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="picUpload(this.files[0])" >
</form>

<canvas id="cnvsForFormat" width="400" height="266"></canvas>
```

### SCRIPT

```
window.picUpload = function(frmData) {
  console.log("picUpload ran: " + frmData);

    var cnvs=document.getElementById("cnvsForFormat");
    console.log("cnvs: " + cnvs);
    var ctx=cnvs.getContext("2d");
    cnvs.style.border="1px solid #c3c3c3";

    var img = new Image;

    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(frmData);

    img.onload = function() {
      var picWidth = this.width;
      var picHeight = this.height;
      var wdthHghtRatio = picHeight/picWidth;

      console.log('picWidth: ' + Number(picWidth));
      console.log('picHeight: ' + Number(picHeight));
      console.log('wdthHghtRatio: ' + wdthHghtRatio);

      if (Number(picWidth) > 400) {
        var newHeight = Math.round(Number(400) * wdthHghtRatio);
      } else {
        return false;
      };

      document.getElementById('cnvsForFormat').height = newHeight;
      console.log('width: ' + picWidth + " h: " + picHeight);
      console.log('width: 400  h: ' + newHeight);
      //Must change the width and height settings in order to decrease the image size, but
        //it needs to be proportional to the original dimensions.
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, 400, newHeight);
    };
```

[jsFiddle Upload Image and Draw to Canvas with New Size](http://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/5xdr9/)

Comment: Basically, yes. PNG is lossless, unlike JPEG, and not limited to 256 colours like GIF, and it has compression unlike BMP. So it makes the most sense to save it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native format of html5 canvas content is a bitmap.

Actually it might be best described as a pixel-map, but think of it as a bitmap.

You can't right-click-save-as a canvas element, but you can:

- get the canvas bitmap as a png dataURL using .toDataURL().
- get the canvas bitmap as a jpg dataURL using .toDataURL('image/jpeg').
- get/set the bitmap pixel data using context.getImageData.

Comment: quote:  "The canvas element represents a resolution-dependent bitmap canvas"  [w3.org Canvas](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/canvas.html)